# pandas groupby difference in days, subset, combination on another column

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a mobile repair data as shown below.

Which is sorted based on ID and Date.

```
ID  Status  Date    Cost
0   1   F   2017-06-22  500
1   1   M   2017-07-22  100
7   1   F   2018-06-22  600
9   1   M   2018-08-22  150
10  1   F   2019-03-22  750
2   2   M   2017-06-29  200
5   2   F   2017-09-29  600
6   2   F   2018-01-29  500
16  2   M   2018-03-29  100
17  2   M   2018-04-29  100
18  2   F   2018-12-29  500
3   3   M   2017-03-20  300
8   3   F   2018-06-20  700
11  3   M   2018-10-20  250
4   4   M   2017-08-10  800
12  4   F   2018-06-10  100
13  4   F   2018-10-10  500
14  4   M   2019-01-10  200
15  4   F   2019-06-10  600
```

F - Failure

M - Maintenance

Q1) My aim is to find out the impact of M(Maintenance) in increasing the duration for F (failure).

ie. How failure time is varying with a Maintenance in between them.

```
df['D'] = df.groupby('ID')['Date'].diff().dt.days
```

First I am trying to subset the above data frame with consecutive F-F pattern as shown below

F-F pattern (consecutive F-F - ID wise)

```
ID  Status  Date    Cost
5   2   F   2017-09-29  600
6   2   F   2018-01-29  500
12  4   F   2018-06-10  100
13  4   F   2018-10-10  500
```

Please help me the code in pandas to get above subset.

And similarly I would like to subset M-F, F-M and M-M pattern and analyse the duration. Please propose your thoughts apart from subsetting,  to solve this problem.

Expected F-M subset

```
ID  Status  Date    Cost
0   1   F   2017-06-22  500
1   1   M   2017-07-22  100
7   1   F   2018-06-22  600
9   1   M   2018-08-22  150
6   2   F   2018-01-29  500
16  2   M   2018-03-29  100
8   3   F   2018-06-20  700
11  3   M   2018-10-20  250
13  4   F   2018-10-10  500
14  4   M   2019-01-10  200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#convert to datetimes and sorting
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.sort_values(['ID', 'Date', 'Status'])

#differenc column
df['D'] = df.groupby('ID')['Date'].diff().dt.days
#create statust column with next and previous values per groups
df['S1'] = df.groupby('ID')['Status'].shift() + '-'+ df['Status']
df['S2'] = df['Status']  + '-'+ df.groupby('ID')['Status'].shift(-1)

#filter by boolean indexing
pat = 'F-F'
df1 = df[df['S1'].eq(pat) | df['S2'].eq(pat)]
print (df1)
    ID Status       Date  Cost      D   S1   S2
5    2      F 2017-09-29   600   92.0  M-F  F-F
6    2      F 2018-01-29   500  122.0  F-F  M-F
12   4      F 2018-06-10   100  304.0  M-F  F-F
13   4      F 2018-10-10   500  122.0  F-F  M-F
```

---

```
pat = 'F-M'   
df1 = df[(df['S1'].eq(pat) | df['S2'].eq(pat))]
print (df1)
    ID Status       Date  Cost      D   S1   S2
0    1      F 2017-06-22   500    NaN  NaN  F-M
1    1      M 2017-07-22   100   30.0  F-M  M-F
7    1      F 2018-06-22   600  335.0  M-F  F-M
9    1      M 2018-08-22   150   61.0  F-M  M-F
6    2      F 2018-01-29   500  122.0  F-F  F-M
16   2      M 2018-03-29   100   59.0  F-M  M-M
8    3      F 2018-06-20   700  457.0  M-F  F-M
11   3      M 2018-10-20   250  122.0  F-M  NaN
13   4      F 2018-10-10   500  122.0  F-F  F-M
14   4      M 2019-01-10   200   92.0  F-M  M-F
```

Comment: is it possible to subset F-M pattern, please share your code, if possible

Comment: @ALI - How working if change `pat = 'F-F'` to `pat = 'F-M'` ?

Comment: @ALI - You can specify in this variable your pattern `pat='F-F', pat='M-F', pat='F-M'`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196465/discussion-between-ali-and-jezrael).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57252821/groupby-filter-based-on-consecutive-sequence-sorted-and-id-and-date-column/57253547#57253547

Comment: please look into above question, no one could answered.